# SRGAN model is not learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, generative-adversarial-network

As the model is not learning I wanted to make sure whether I coded the below lines correctly.

This lines shows the architecture of SRGAN model:-

```
generated_image = generator(input_low_res_img_layer)
discriminator_output = discriminator(generated_image)
fake_features = vgg_model(generated_image)

GAN_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = input_low_res_img_layer, outputs = [discriminator_output,fake_features])
```

Below lines are used for the compilation of the models:-

```
my_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
vgg_model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=my_optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer= my_optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
GAN_model.compile(loss=['binary_crossentropy','mse'], loss_weights=[1e-3,1],metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Below lines are GAN and discriminator model fit codes:

```
    discriminator.trainable = True
    discriminator.fit(real_and_fake_images,real_and_fake_labels)
    discriminator.trainable = False

    GAN_model.fit(low_res_img_batch, [np.ones((batch_size,1)),vgg_model(high_res_img_batch)])
```

[The image shows the result of the training. The first metric of each mini-batch is for the discriminator and the second line is for the GAN network.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9f1TW.png)

In case needed, [Full code here](https://github.com/Dipon12/Implementation-of-SRGAN-in-Keras/blob/master/Implementation_of_SRGAN_in_Keras.ipynb)

Comment: Not sure, what if you replace fit by train_on_batch?

Comment: @OrpheeFaucoz as far as I have understood using fit with epochs =1 is similar to using train_on_batch.